# Plotting heatmap values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot points for a heatmap using the Google Maps API. I'm extracting the data from my CSV file and formatting it into an array just fine. However the map just won't load. I have another solution that I used hardcoded data for which it works fine.

The data comes in the form of:

```
Latitude,Longitude,Weighting
data1,data2,data3,
data1,data2,data3,
.....etc
```

Theres about 150 points to plot.

I think the issue is to do with calling the function correctly. Originally I had a:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', createMap);
```

line in, but the function is being called from my AJAX function so I didn't think I needed it anymore.

Am I correct in omitting that line or is that even the issue?

Thanks

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Data Extraction</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerymobile/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/September2GData.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);},
    complete: function() {createMap();}
 });
});

var lines = [];

function processData(allText) {

var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');

for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    if (data.length == headers.length) {
        var tarr = [];
        for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
            tarr.push(data[j]);
            lines.push(tarr[j])
        }
    }
   }
 }

 function createMap(){

var map;

var dataPoint1 = parseFloat(lines[0]);
var dataPoint2 = parseFloat(lines[1]);

var heatMapData = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(dataPoint1, dataPoint2)
];

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(dataPoint1, dataPoint2),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var heatMap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer(heatMapData);
heatMap.setMap(map);

alert("Finished");
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  You have a sample you can post or link to?

Comment: I'll edit the main section now to include the data format. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's creating the map first before processData has had a chance to complete, or at least firing `createMap` and `processData` at more or less the same time. I suggest using a callback so that `processData` passes `lines` to `createMap` once it's completed processing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/September2GData.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data, function (lines) {
        createMap(lines);
      });
    }
  });
});

function processData(allText, callback) {
  var lines = [];
  // code for lines
  callback(lines);
}

function createMap(lines) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy. I implemented your changes there and the map still isn't loading. I've tested to ensure that the createMap function is still being called but the map isn't plotting.

Comment: Have you made sure that you're using CSS to add a height and width to #map-canvas? And are you sure that the data is actually loading?

Comment: I hadn't put in the CSS. Thanks a million for that Andy!!